# Updating data in charts, highcharts with angular, highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

Trying out a highcharts directive for angular, highcharts-ng. https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

I have some problem with updating the data. Updating the series values is no problem. But I cant update the X-axis titles. I have a js-fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/user1572526/3stqK/2/

I have the chartConfig in my factory:

```
myapp.factory('Chart', function () {
    var chartConfig = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['old bar title', 'old bar title 2 ']
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },

        loading: false
    }
    return chartConfig;
});
```

Then I expose it in my controller:

```
myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, Chart) {
    $scope.chartConfig = Chart;
```

And finally a function to set some new values

```
$scope.update = function () {
     $scope.chartConfig.title.text = "Setting new title"; //Works    
    $scope.chartConfig.series = [{ //Works
        "name": "Updated data",
            "data": [1, 2, 4, 7, 3]
    }];
    $scope.chartConfig.xAxis = [{ //NOT WORKING
        categories: ['new bar title', 'new bar title2']
    }]
    console.log($scope.chartConfig);
}
```

Everything works except the X-Axis.

Any idea what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The xAxis should be an object and not an array. The config should be set up like so:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['old bar title', 'old bar title 2 ']
    }
```

And the update should be:

```
    $scope.chartConfig.xAxis.categories = ['new bar title', 'new bar title2'];
```